# Create a DNS URL for aws public s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to provide a customized DNS URL to aws s3 bucket. I can access the files of my s3 bucket as URL `https://<s3-bucket-name>.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/folder-name/file.png` But I want to provide URL as `https://abc.example.xyz` . Not sure how can I do it.

Tried steps - I tried with using Route 53 and mapped the `abc.example.xyz` with `<s3-bucket-name>.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com` but that didn't work.

The purpose of this bucket is to store files like jpg and pdf, which can be accessed via URL.

Comment: On Route53, did you setup A Record or Alias or C-Name to point to your s3 bucket?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it with C-name, but it didn't work

Comment: Amazon recommends to use Alias instead of CName. Try setting the alias of your domain to the s3 bucket.

Comment: I tried but it was not showing S3 endpoint in drop-down

Comment: Is static website hosting enabled on the s3 bucket and is it publicly accessible?

Comment: No, as mentioned this bucket is used for accessing the pdf and images through URL, we don't have any website hosting into that. There is no html page or anything like that

Answer (score 1):

The bucket name has to be the same as of the customized DNS, then the CNAME works well in AWS route 53.
I created a bucket with name `abc.example.xyz` and then used CNAME `abc.example.xyz` with `abc.example.xyz.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com`. It works fine.